# Fetching posts made by facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have a mobile app that share images to facebook.
Images on my wall are posted with the text "XX minutes ago via [app name]"

This app is owned by me.
How can I get (using FQL, or any other method) list of all items shared by this app?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and maybe the only) way is to store them in your own Database right after posting.

For example, you can use the callback function of the FB.ui dialog if you are using the JS SDK:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
  caption: 'An example caption',
}, function(response){
  //callback function
});
```

But i am not sure if this allowed for privacy reasons. I would at least tell the user that you store it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably keep all posts ids and then query each one of them, though it seems odd.

Comment: You may not be able to do that, if the user sets the visibility to something else than public. else you would need the user access token of the poster.

Comment: Thanks, your comment was the right answer - using the user token :)